# get result from mysql with multidimentional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i have a multidimentional array and i dont know how to get any row from the database that is equal to any of the multidimentional array id `
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 828
[tok] => 90dcddc388d9b1
[user_id] => 1
[category_name] => Medicine,
[created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:08:55
)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 829
        [tok] => f3404ba92a40f7
        [user_id] => 1
        [name] => Medicine
        [created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:18:09
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 830
        [tok] => 2669483afacc47
        [user_id] => 1
        [name] => forever
        [created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:18:12
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 831
        [tok] => 9b72ba6ab4d8d0
        [user_id] => 1
        [name] => joe
        [created_at] => 2020-12-03 00:18:14
    )
```

)
`
for example i want to get any id from the database that is equal to any id in this multidimentional array array

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach function like:

```
foreach ($multidimentional as $k => $v) { $array[$v['id']] = $v; }
```

Then try: `var_dump($array);`

Answer (score 0):

First you should gather all the ids from the array using:

```
$idsArray = array_column($yourArray,'id');
```

And then search into your database:

```
Model::whereIn('id', $idsArray)->get(); // laravel eloquent ORM
```

OR

```
DB::table('YOUR_DB_TABLE')->whereIn('id', $idsArray)->get(); // laravel query builder
```

OR using the php mysqli:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE id in = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", implode(',', $idsArray));
$stmt->execute()
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: not working says Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool

Comment: This is just an example, not a tested code .. just explaining the approach